# Network problem after detaching my app from Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I detached my react-native code from Expo (v 31) because I need to use Bluetooth, and made `sudo gem install cocoapods`, `pod setup` and `pod install` in the ios folder.

When I run my app from Xcode, the simulator opens and displays:

> There was a problem loading the requested app. It looks like you may
>   me be using a LAN URL. Make sure your device is on the same network as
>   the server or try using a tunnel
>
> expd03d..........
>
> 192.168...
>
> Make sure you are serving your project from XDE or exp (Could not
>   connect to the server)

I have found this [post](https://forums.expo.io/t/ejected-app-not-loading-the-requested-app-30-0-0/13673/14) but it says that expoKit 2.8.2 solve the problem - but I have 2.9.0

I know it is a possible when using Expo, but I have detached it. Why does it display it ?

Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: how you run the app? after ejected from expo into native?

Comment: Directly from Xcode. I click the Run button, that launches the simulator

Comment: Connect your mobile and enable usb debugging on mobile and run command: react-native run ios

Comment: You think the simulator can be the source of the problem ? (I can't connect my phone now, I have an Android, I can have access to an Iphone, but tomorrow only)

Comment: Do you on USB debugging mode in your Android mobile?

Comment: I activated USB debugging mode on my Android yes. When you say "react-native run ios" you mean "react-native run-ios" ? I did it but it launches a simulator. I am sorry I have never debugged with USB, what command do you use to simulate on your phone via USB (I have found via Android studio, but not as you say)

Comment: Actually for android device, i connect my cable on mobile, and i make a command called react-native run-android. Please refer this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Comment: Ok, I did it I have an error when building "/user/MyName/Library/Android/sdk" does not exist. I have to investigate it but I think it is another problem

Comment: yes you have to install and accept license of sdk.